# How to make the page in developed from Scratch using Html, CSS and JS my homepage in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to use the page I design from scratch using HTML, CSS and JavaScript as the default homepage to WordPress.

The page is not on WordPress. I created it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a template file by adding this line to the first line

```
<?php /* Template Name: Homepage Template */ ?>
```

place it in your theme folder

Go to WordPress admin and create a new page, select template option to be Homepage Template, save it.

Now go to WordPress settings, Reading and select it as homepage.

Hope it helps